# Magento: how to load multiple rows instead of one?

Tags: php, mysql, magento

Suppose I extract something from a model using load:

```
    $model = Mage::getModel('modulename/modelName')->load($userinfo->getId(),'user_id');
```

then I want $model to be an array where user_id = $userinfo->getId(), basically return all rows where $userinfo->getId() is the user_id, currently it returns only one row which is the first row, there are more than 10 rows with the same user_id..

then I want to do

```
foreach ($model as $m)
$m->addData($data);
            try {
                $insertId = $m->save()->getId();
            } catch (Exception $e){
            }
```

So I want the load method to return multiple rows, not just one single row. Currently it returns only one row.

**edit:**
My code is not working:

My Collection class located at Namespace/Modulename/Model/ModelName/Collection.php

```
<?php

class Namespace_Modulename_Model_Mysql4_ModelName_Collection extends    Mage_Core_Model_Mysql4_Collection_Abstract
{
    public function _construct(){
        parent::_construct();
        $this->_init('modulename/modelName');
    }
}
```

My code:

```
 $data = array(
                            'someField' => 'someValue'
                        );
$model_collection = Mage::getModel('modulename/modelName_collection');
                    $model_collection = $model_collection->addFieldToFilter('user_id', $userinfo->getId());
                    foreach ($model_collection as $model) {
                        try {
                            $insertId = $model->save()->getId();
                        } catch (Exception $e){
                        }
                    }
```

I want to add $data in model

Comment: Please follow the posting guidelines in [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).  We cannot reproduce the problem from this code alone, and I'm not entirely sure what you want as a result -- an example would help clarify your wording.

Comment: I have edited the question and clarified, @Prune, I want a method like SQL "WHERE", but it should return multiple rows, not just one.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use collection

```
$collection = Mage::getResourceModel('modulename/modelName_collection');
$collection->addFieldToFilter('user_id', $userinfo->getId());
```